# How to use Colors in String.Xml file in Java Code

Tags: android, paint

I have colors in my String.xml file, as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>


      <string name="txtEmail">Email </string>
       <string name="txtPin">Pin Code</string>
       <string name="lblProtected"> Protected</string>

       <color name="MiscellaneousPercent">#ffff992b</color>
       <color name="MusicPercent">#ffffdd58</color>
       <color name="PicturesPercent">#ff48aa71</color>
       <color name="eBooksPercent">#ff00cff9</color>
       <color name="DocumentsPercent">#ff019df2</color>
</resources>
```

I want to use the these colors in class in my projects in order to iterate through the colors, by code.

```
    public class BreakDownBar extends View {

        public BreakDownBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }


            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
                        paint.setColor(/*I want to use the colors HERE*/); 
            }


                }
}
```

How can I use the colors in the `onDraw` method in `SetColor()`like above? Can I put the colors in the String.XMl file in an array? 
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make use of your Context, and provide your resource in a array format and use it.

```
public class BreakDownBar extends View {

    Context context=null;
int res[]={R.color.black,R.color.blue,R.color.white,R.color.pink,R.color.grey};

        public BreakDownBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            this.context=context;
        }


            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                       Paint paint = new Paint();
                       paint.setColor(res[i]));
            }


                }
}
```

Comment: i know that, what i want is that the color will iterate across the colors i have. in code you gave me the paint will have the black colors always!!

Comment: i want to put the colors in the String.xml in a n array

Comment: yeah.. cool. If u had asked for the iteration process at the earlier it wud have been more easier.. not a problem though. happy that it helped you.. keep going..

Answer (score 4):

Use like this

```
context.getResources().getColor(R.color.MusicPercent);
```

Answer (score 1):

//you can use by get resource

```
paint.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.custom_red));
```